# Tiling a hexagonal chessboard with "tribones"

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, tiling

A *tribone* is a tile made of three hexagons in a line.

A *hexagonal chessboard* is a hexagonal grid of 91 cells in the shape of a larger hexagon.

> When 30 tribones are placed on a hexagonal chessboard without overlap, what are the possible locations of the uncovered space?

[image]

Comment: are we gonna ignore symmetry? or the answer would be 6x?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Colour in all cells in the top horizontal row in Red, the second in Blue, then Green,  Red,  Blue and so on.

```
     R R R R R R
    B B B B B B B
   G G G G G G G G
  R R R R R R R R R
 B B B B B B B B B B
G G G G G G G G G G G
 R R R R R R R R R R
  B B B B B B B B B 
   G G G G G G G G  
    R R R R R R R
     B B B B B B
```

*Thanks to Mike Earnest for the diagram!*

As you place tiles on the board, denote the number of each colour remaining uncovered at any stage as R, G, B.

Each piece must either cover 3 cells of a single colour, or one of each. Either way,  the relative numbers of each colour modulo 3 remains unaltered,  i.e. (R-G)%3, (G-B)%3 and (B-R)%3 are constant.

Initially there are 6+9+10+7=32 reds (=2 mod 3), and the same number of blue.  There are 8+11+8=27 greens (=0 mod 3). So R=B mod 3 and G=R+1 mod 3.

Once there is only one cell left uncovered, that cell must therefore be Green. So it must be on row 3, 6 or 9.

By rotating through 60 degrees in either direction and applying the same logic, the uncovered cell must be one of the seven highlighted in the other answers - either the central cell or 3 rows in from any two adjoining edges.

Comment: Thanks for the image - I can't see the edit history on this device so don't know who to thank :)

Comment: That was me, nice job on the solution!

Answer (score 5):

Adding to @Oray's answer, here are constructions:

> [image: 6]
>  (rotate for blue dots)
>  [image: 1]

I've reduced it to these hexagons:

> [image]
>  Those labelled 2, because each 'tribone' must cover a 1, a 2 and a 3 and there are 30 1s, 30 3s but 31 2s.

Comment: I reduced it to the same ones - I'm trying to find something to rule out the other 2s.

Answer (score 4):

There are

> 7 uncovered place possibilities

as shown in the figure below:

> [image]

I am working on how to show that these are only possible places by programming or by some logical-deduction and post it soon!